# python sqlite create id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT

Tags: python, sqlite

Creating a simple database and have the rows with an id so I can select row values later:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("APIlan.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENERGYLOG (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, totalenergy REAL)''')
c.execute("INSERT INTO ENERGYLOG VALUES (?);", (total_energy,))
conn.commit()       
conn.close()
```

Error `sqlite3.OperationalError: table ENERGYLOG has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied`

Second try:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("APIlan.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ENERGYLOG (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, totalenergy REAL)''')
c.execute("INSERT INTO ENERGYLOG VALUES (?,?);", (NULL,total_energy,))
conn.commit()       
conn.close()
```

Error `NameError: name 'NULL' is not defined`

Without supplying the value for id, how do I get it into the table?  Thanks.

Comment: NULL -> None...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have two solutions.

1.Your first try, if you only want to insert the columns you choose, you can follow this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (column1, column2, column3,...columnN)] VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

so, you can write this:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO ENERGYLOG (totalenergy) VALUES (?);", (total_energy,))
```

2.Your second try, if you want to insert all columns, you can replace 'NULL' to 'None':

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO ENERGYLOG VALUES (?, ?);", (None, total_energy))
```

Because python don't know 'NULL'.

In SQL we use 'NULL' and in python we use 'None'.

hope it can help you!

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly list what columns you want to insert into:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO ENERGYLOG (totalenergy) VALUES (?);", (total_energy,))
```

---

As far as parameterizing `NULL`, you should specify `None` as the parameter value:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO ENERGYLOG VALUES (?, ?);", (None, total_energy))
```

Or, use `NULL` and a single parameter:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO ENERGYLOG VALUES (NULL, ?);", (total_energy,))
```